# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null" occurring in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have an accordion module that has quite a few moving parts. In short, it pulls in data from a Google Fusion Table and adds it to different areas of the accordion. A working example can be seen here. http://csgjusticecenter.org/code/SDWeb/accordionOld.html

For whatever reason, when I add it to my WordPress site and click on one of the headings, I get an error in Chrome saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null." In FF, I get an error saying "TypeError: resourceCategories is null."

This page is an example of how it doesn't work on the page: http://csgjusticecenter.org/code/SDWeb/intranetAccordion.html.
If I put the accordion in an iframe (the second example on the page), it works as it should.

The code for the working page (which is the source for the iframe) is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">        </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href='http://csgjusticecenter.org/code/SDWeb/resourceAccordion.css' />
<script src="http://csgjusticecenter.org/code/SDWeb/accordionResources.js"></script>
<script src="http://csgjusticecenter.org/code/SDWeb/resourceAccordion.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<script>buildPage();</script>
<div id="wrapper2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why do I get an error when the accordion is in a Wordpress site, but not when it is added on its own?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

This is the function that is called when a div with class `.accordionButton` is clicked.

```
function programResources(){

    var query = "SELECT Category, Name, Website, Description FROM " +
        '13aGTztEz7_XOWk7U_OzelJqr3Qr2yeFxv8ntt7FP ' + "WHERE 'Category' = '" +  resourceName1 + "'";
    var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

    // Construct the URL
    var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'];
    url.push('?sql=' + encodedQuery);
    url.push('&key=AIzaSyD9Otr9A4pq624Ja9hRFMpUpBnyQAr06M0');
    url.push('&callback=?');

    // Send the JSONP request using jQuery
    $.ajax({
      url: url.join(''),
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function (data) {
        var rows = data['rows'];
        var resourceCategories = document.getElementById(contentDivId);
        var containerContainer = document.createElement('div');
        containerContainer.className = 'containerContainer';              
        var infoContainer = document.createElement('div');
        infoContainer.className = 'infoContainer';
        infoContainer.innerHTML = 'Click resource title to learn more';
        infoContainer.id = 'infoContainer';


        for (var i in rows) {
          var category = rows[i][0];
          var resourceName2 = rows[i][1];
          var siteUrl = rows[i][2];
          var desc = rows[i][3];
          var divID = rows[i][4];


          var resourceName = document.createElement('div');
          resourceName.className= 'resourceContainer';
          resourceName.id = resourceName2 + 'resource';


          var resourceText = document.createElement('span');
          resourceText.className='resourceText';          
          resourceText.innerHTML = resourceName2;


          resourceName.appendChild(resourceText);
          containerContainer.appendChild(resourceName);
          resourceCategories.appendChild(containerContainer);
          resourceCategories.appendChild(infoContainer);


        }

      }
    });
    goScroll = 0;
};
```

The error comes up after

`resourceCategories.appendChild(containerContainer);`

Also, this function (along as a few others) is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Where within your code is this error occuring? why are you including jquery twice? where is `buildPage()` defined?

Comment: @KevinB The error occurs in resourceAccordion.js (line 96) whenever I click on a heading. Including jquery twice was a mistake that I have removed. 'buildPage()' is defined in accordionResources.js.

Comment: can you include the relevant code in your question?

Comment: @KevinB I've added the function that is called during a click event. Sorry I left it out before.

Comment: My guess is `var resourceCategories = document.getElementById(contentDivId);` isn't finding the content div you expect it to.

Comment: @KevinB Within `$('div').on('click', '.accordionButton', function(){`, I am setting contentDivID using `var contentDiv = $(this).next().attr('id'); window.contentDivId = contentDiv;`

Comment: that's fine, but `document.getElementById(contentDivId);` isn't finding any elements. That's the root of your problem.

Comment: Any idea as to why that could be happening? Before I click, there is an element with the correct divID.

Comment: @KevinB On a side note, can you think of a reason why I am not having this problem when the accordion is used as a [standalone](http://csgjusticecenter.org/code/SDWeb/accordionOld.html)?